# Convert hdf5 to pandas dataframe (see details)

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a .hdf5 file with the following structure:

```
/keys                   ------------Root group
/keys/axis0              -----> dataset
/keys/axis1
/keys/block0_items       -----> dataset
/keys/block0_values      -----> dataset
/keys/block1_items       -----> dataset
/keys/block1_values      -----> dataset
```

How to I convert this file into a single dataframe.?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you running into?  There are answers on loading .hdf5 files with multiple keys, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56325114/9987623) one.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62364413/9987623) answer may provide some help too.  It concatenates different parts of the file after they are read into pandas.

Comment: I think my answe here and the provided links might be of help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74127100/5838180