# Problem when reading h5 file in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read a .h5 file with the code above. Actually, I only want to read three specific columns of the file (Mvir_all, pid, and id). The file has created so pid == -1, or pid != -1. If pid != -1, then pid is equal to the id of some other row.

However, I've written the code above to check if all the pids distinct than -1 are contained in the rest of ids, and I get that there are several that aren't. This is impossible, the only possibility is that there is something wrong in the code. Can someome help me?

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pandas as pd


DIC = {}; gal_file = "file.h5"

f =  h5py.File(gal_file, 'r')
print(f.keys())
for n in ["Mvir_all", "pid", "id"]:
        if(n=="Mvir_all")or(n=="pid")or(n=="id"):
                print(n)
                DIC[str(n)] = f[n][:]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DIC)

halos = df[df['pid'] == -1]
subhalos = df[df['pid'] != -1]

print(len(halos), len(subhalos))

halos = halos.reset_index()
subhalos = subhalos.reset_index()

pid = subhalos['pid']
id = halos['id']

# Check if all values of "pid" from subhalos are in "id" from halos
all_pids_in_halos = subhalos['pid'].isin(halos['id']).all()

if all_pids_in_halos:
    print("All values of 'pid' from subhalos are in 'id' from halos.")
else:
    print("Not all values of 'pid' from subhalos are in 'id' from halos.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read your h5 file with the `read_hdf` [pandas function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

gal_file = "file.h5"

df = pd.read_hdf(gal_file, columns=["Mvir_all", "pid", "id"])
...
```

After, the question is not clean enough to understand what you want.

Comment: The problem is that something must be wrong in the way I'm reading the file because it's impossible I get the output "Not all values of 'pid' from subhalos are in 'id' from halos" with the code I wrote because of the construction of the data. I will try your code.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. I get the following error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 21, in <module>
    df = pd.read_hdf(gal_file, columns=["Mvir_all", "pid", "id"])
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 377, in read_hdf
    raise ValueError('No dataset in HDF5 file.')
ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file."

Comment: Hello, By searching your error, it seems that the pandas is waiting for another structure than the one created by h5py. I think you should see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388502/read-hdf5-file-created-with-h5py-using-pandas/74127100#74127100.